# Flex Vertically Aligned Text Mac vs Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, vertical-alignment

I am looking into an issue in a Flex application where on OS X text is shifted up a couple pixels compared to windows. Every text field is not vertically aligned to the middle it is more towards the top.

Found a thread here but no real solution http://forums.adobe.com/message/2189821

Anyone know how to solve this problem in a way that applies to both systems.

Comment: I believe it is using @font-face in a css file

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to conditionally adjust component positioning when OS X is detected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               preinitialize="onPreinitialize()"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function onPreinitialize():void 
            {   
                Alert.show((-1 != Capabilities.os.search(new RegExp('mac', 'i'))) ? 'Replace this Alert with code which adjusts text positioning in order for it to appear the same as when it runs on Windows.' : 'No need to adjust text', Capabilities.os);
            }   
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: That is definitely a solution. However seems taxing on your application to need to add this feature checking. This is most likely a bug Adobe needs to fix.

Comment: "This is most likely a bug Adobe needs to fix."

Unfortunately that's quite a common situation with Flex/Adobe. If you dig around in base classes you'll find comments which often begin with "This is a bug/isn't working/is supposed to do ___."